# Steps for migrating user home directory to OneDrive for Business

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365, onedrive-for-business

I need to migrate or move the HomeDrives of all corporate users into OneDrive for Business.
There are approximately 600+ user directories in a total of 4.5 TB

The entire users have been assigned of minimum Microsoft 365 Enterprise ***E3*** license to allow 1 TB OneDrive quota.

Microsoft Office desktop client is already using Office 365 (Click to Run).

Group Policy has been configured to map each users H: drive into \DFSSVR05-VM\HomeDirs%USERNAME%\

How to transfer all of their data into the OneDrive without manual Cut & Pasting to C:\Users%USERNAME% \OneDrive\

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this article about "Migrate Users Home Drives to OneDrive for Business with PowerShell":

https://lazyadmin.nl/office-365/migrate-users-home-drives-to-onedrive-for-business-with-powershell/